# how do i compare values and assign condition in tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a table with members, date and results. The date represent the month for which all the results were generated for various members. Table stores results for multiple months. Now, i want to compare results of current month with last month for particular member and assign “equal” , “>” or “<” sign based on their values. How can i do that in tableau?
Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thank you.

Comment: There are lots of different ways, but see [this](https://playfairdata.com/how-to-compare-the-last-two-full-days-weeks-or-months-in-tableau/) article for a pretty good example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lookup function. Assuming you have below data:

[image]

you can create a lookup function in tableau with below expression:

```
LOOKUP(sum([Result]),-1)
```

[image]

Note you need to use an aggregate function on your measure

After creating a lookup column create a calculated field to do data comparison:
[image]

This should give you the result you are looking for:
[image]

You can edit the table calculations to define the reset level for your calculation:
[image]